# Adding tailwind utilities doesn't get shown

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

I've recently started working with Tailwindcss/Next.js and I want to give a button a box-like shadow with a new utility with pure CSS. But for some reason, it doesn't apply the changes. Have I forgotten something?

index.jsx:

```
...
<button className="text-xl font-bold italic cursor-pointer border-textwhite
 border-2 w-52 bg-primary h-10 uppercase box-shadow-black">
Buy Now
</button>
...
```

index.css:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer utilities {
  .box-shadow-black {
    box-shadow: 0.125rem 0.125rem 0 0px #000;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works but you have small bugs:  `border-textwhite` insted of this: `text-red-500` and conflict `border` and `border-2` i left `border-2` and added more shadow `0.2rem` to display effect **better**! Also remember about how to install [**tailwindcss**](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs) with **next.js**.
Good Luck ;-)

index.js

```
import Head from "next/head";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-screen flex-col gap-5">
        <button className="text-xl font-bold italic cursor-pointer text-red-500 border-2 w-52 bg-primary h-10 uppercase box-shadow-black">
          Buy Now
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

globals.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


@layer utilities {
  .box-shadow-black {
    box-shadow: 0.2rem 0.2rem 0.2rem 0px black;
  }
}
```

---

output :

[image]

*"next": "12.0.7","react": "17.0.2","tailwindcss": "^3.0.5"*